# Preflight for Google Cloud Storage signed URL not returning CORS response headers

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to perform a signed [resumable upload to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload). Our frontend is running up against CORS restrictions on the initial request: 
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

The response headers show no CORS headers:

`alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 20:28:32 GMT
expires: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 20:28:32 GMT
server: UploadServer
status: 200
x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2Ups1tKbTbhPmsjrPXbIuIUyQt135AlSJ1n7-7XTwMrtQ2vUvn1WwpX3a_iusfmsXHaufdf5B3H2PzmDONs2wW7tKkLarYoxrVyWalhaX6FzGQPoRW0`

Debugging, I sent a curl request mimicking our frontend's request:

`curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-goog-resumable" \
     -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
     -H "Origin: https://www.example.com" \
     -X OPTIONS -I https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/...`

Again, the response contains no CORS response headers:

`HTTP/2 200 
x-guploader-uploadid: AEnB2UqwKiRSJjHjF9mzsZRMODdQmF6xhUAhdeEenuD0_WXmxpVA6n0i_HWY2NOJxvXS2t_I4IoFW_yvz6lssMz_HVmvlswL5NilGC3wE2YT0-L9aD7Pf1Q
date: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 21:39:53 GMT
expires: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 21:39:53 GMT
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-length: 0
server: UploadServer
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"`

I've set my bucket CORS settings with `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://bucket` where cors.json contains `[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"], "origin": ["*"]}]`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anybody know why it happens?

Comment: The same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734032/google-cloud-storage-cors-settings-doesnt-work-for-signed-urls

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?

Comment: Please see this thread that includes more detailed answers https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/347

Answer (score 11):

I have found a solution. I had to add x-goog-resumable to the list of response headers.

My CORS file is

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": [
        "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "x-goog-resumable"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "POST", "OPTIONS"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

At least preflight started to work

Comment: Hello, please can you explain where should I add this code?

Comment: This is a sample configuration, which can be used in gsutil command https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cors

Comment: Maybe good to mention that 'Canonicalized_Extension_Headers', so `x-goog-resumable` must be included when determining your url-signature, see [here e.g..](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2000)

Comment: Wow, this is a lifesaver. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SlawekRewaj This approach is working. I am also stuck in similar case, in mycase, I have to pass "Authorization" header in the request for GCS (due to some security reasons of the backend microservice). Its working well when I don't use 'Authorization' and remove the microservice. But this can't be done at prod. how can I put 'Authorization' in request. 

 GCS CORS config is [{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "PATCH", "PUT", "POST"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Origin", "x-goog-resumable"]}]

Comment: @JayendraSingh I'm not sure I understand what you try to do. Do you call GCS from the microservice? Why do you need Authorization header in GCS?

Comment: I was facing the same problem. One way I fixed it by changing the responseHeader to:
"responseHeader": ["*"]. I wouldn't say that it's a perfect solution, but if someone does stumble upon this. This might be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I Had the same issue.I fixed by adding:

```
headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*','Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'}
```

to the ajax request signed URL.

Comment: Requests shouldn't need an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header - I suspect that one does nothing at all, but perhaps the Content-Type header could be helping for binary uploads.