# Google Cloud Storage: CORS settings doesn't work for signed URLs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The response of `PUT` request with signed URL doesn't contain header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

```py
import os
from datetime import timedelta

import requests
from google.cloud import storage

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = <path to google credentials>
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
policies = [
    {
        'origin': ['*'],
        'method': ['PUT'],
    }
]
bucket.cors = policies
bucket.update()
blob = bucket.blob('new_file')
url = blob.generate_signed_url(timedelta(days=30), method='PUT')
response = requests.put(url, data='some data')

for header in response.headers.keys():
    print(header)
```

Output:

```
X-GUploader-UploadID
ETag
x-goog-generation
x-goog-metageneration
x-goog-hash
x-goog-stored-content-length
x-goog-stored-content-encoding
Vary
Content-Length
Date
Server
Content-Type
Alt-Svc
```

As you can see there is no CORS-headers. So, can I conclude that GCS doesn't support CORS properly/fully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) allows interactions between resources from different origins. **By default, in Google Cloud Storage it is prohibited/disabled in order to prevent malicious behavior.**

You can enable it either using [Cloud Libraries](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.cors), Rest API or Cloud SDK, keeping in mind following rules:

1. Authenticate using user/service account with the permissions for Cloud Storage type: `FULL_CONTROL`.
2. [Using XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) to get proper CORS headers, use one of the two URLs:

```
- storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]
- [BUCKET_NAME].storage.googleapis.com
```

Origin `storage.cloud.google.com/[BUCKET_NAME]` will not respond with CORS header.

3. Request need proper ORIGIN header to match bucket policy ORIGIN configuration as stated in the point 3 of the [CORS troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#troubleshooting), in case of your code:

```
headers = {
    'ORIGIN': '*'
}
response = requests.put(url, data='some data', headers=headers)

for header in response.headers.keys():
    print(header)
```

gives following output:

```
X-GUploader-UploadID
ETag
x-goog-generation
x-goog-metageneration
x-goog-hash
x-goog-stored-content-length
x-goog-stored-content-encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
Content-Length
Date
Server
Content-Type
```

Comment: This works only for GET requests. But doesn't work for PUT. Look at the code I provided. I do the same things you suggested except the method is PUT.

Comment: BTW DELETE which you used in bucket policy in your example doesn't work as well.

Comment: [Documentation states](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#how_cors_works), that request is pref lighted in any of the other method than: GET, HEAD or POST. That includes: POST and Delete. Did you try to check it?

Comment: Yes. Response on preflight request doesn't contain CORS headers. In my case it's PUT (DELETE checked as well).

Comment: Maybe this article will help: https://blog.francium.tech/google-cloud-storage-and-cors-37236fbb99ba

Comment: The article describes the same way of setting CORS policy I used. I guess it's either a bug or lack of documentation. Is there a way to report a bug to Google dev team?

Comment: I will try to reproduce it next week not later than Tuesday. If the preflight (as described in the example provided) does not get correct headers and it will not work for me either, I will file a public issue for you.

Comment: BTW The same problem reported half a year ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290008/preflight-for-google-cloud-storage-signed-url-not-returning-cors-response-header

Comment: I did reproduce your issue, and updated answer accordingly. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue.  For me the problem was I was using `POST` instead of `PUT`.  Furthermore, I had to set the `Content-Type` of the upload to match the content type used to generate the form.  The default Content-Type in the demo is "application/octet-stream", so I had to change it to be whatever was the content type of the upload. When doing the XMLHttpRequest, I just had to send the file directly instead of using FormData.

This was how I got the signed url.

```
    const options = {
        version: 'v4',
        action: 'write',
        expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    };

    // Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
    const [url] = await storage
        .bucket("lsa-storage")
        .file(upload.id)
        .getSignedUrl(options as any);
```