# How to upload a file to GCS using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a file to GCS using javascript.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562391/track-progress-of-file-upload-to-google-cloud-storage-via-js) which shows how to upload and see the progress of that file.

I also followed the official [documentation](https://github.com/googlearchive/storage-getting-started-javascript)

All of the above worked for me, but now i want to allow anyone who visits my website to upload to the bucket i have. I don't want to authenticate using the button that the documentation shows. I just want anyone to be able to visit the website, upload and see the progress of the upload file.

The main issue i have is that i want users to be able to see the PROGRESS of the upload file. Maybe there is another way.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload file to google cloud storage with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919153/upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you need to:

1. Configure [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket)
2. [Generate signed url for file upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). You can check [example in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734032) how to do it or [example server side app in node.js](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/google-cloud-signedurl-test-case)
3. Use [resumable multiple chunks upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload#upload-resumable) to show upload progress.