# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin when uploading to Google Cloud Storage with PUT method with cors configured in gsutil

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, cloudflare

we have sourced the entire web to find a solution for this issue and still no luck!
We have a website where we let users upload files directly to Google Cloud Storage bucket with a signed upload url generated from the backend, We upload with a PUT request. Whenever the user uploads a file, there is an error in the chrome dev tool console saying

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

We have updated our cors settings for the bucket as follows:

```
$ gsutil cors get gs://{BUCKET_NAME}
[{"method": ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["*"]}]
```

But still, whenever we send the request, no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is returned in the response header.

Few notes: We are using a compute engine instance and our domain name is managed by Cloudflare.

Some articles suggested that this might be a caching issue, but we have been facing this issue for weeks and nothing changed.

I heard that PUT methods might require pre-flight requests to work, I know the theory part of pre-flight requests but I never used it before and not sure what to do, should I add another request before sending the main fetch request, or is it all automatic and happens behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

I will post my comment as an answer, as it is too long for the comment section.

While researching the numerous posts referencing this error I stumbled across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290008/preflight-for-google-cloud-storage-signed-url-not-returning-cors-response-header) that could be related to yours, since the user is uploading files on GCS.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads#initiate-session) you may also find the documentation regarding initiating resumable uploads on GCS.

> When using resumable uploads, you first need to make a POST request to
>   the endpoint to start it and then 1 or more (depending on the number
>   of chunks) PUT requests for the actual upload. When the Origin header
>   is not specified in the first POST, the last chunk will not contain
>   the headers that allow CORS to work and the browser will reject the
>   request, even though it could be actually made (if file gets actually
>   uploaded).

I hope this information helps.