# The CORS header is present on PUT requests but not on OPTIONS requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client, pre-signed-url

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket with the following CORS configuration:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://localhost:8080"],
      "responseHeader": [
        "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "Origin"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

I am generating a signed URL with the following code:

```
let bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
let file = bucket.file(key);

const options = {
    version: "v4",
    action: "write",
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    contentType: "application/zip"
};

let url = await file.getSignedUrl(options))[0];
```

For my requests I am using the following headers:

```
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/zip
```

When I try using a PUT request to upload the data everything works fine and I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header containing my Origin. But when I do a OPTIONS request with the exact same headers it fails to return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I have tried many alterations to my CORS config but none have worked like:

- Changing the origins to `*`
- The different changes described in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290008/preflight-for-google-cloud-storage-signed-url-not-returning-cors-response-header) it's answer and comments.
- The different changes described in [GitHub Google Storage API Issues](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/347)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem with some help from my colleagues, when I was testing the function in Postman the CORS header was not sent as a response to the `OPTIONS` request because the request was missing the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header. When I added this header it worked fine.

Comment: Good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, it told me yesterday I could only accept it tomorrow (which is today).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that as stated on the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#cors-elements) you shouldn't specify OPTIONS in your CORS configuration and notice that Cloud Storage only supports `DELETE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT` for the XML API and `DELETE, GET, HEAD, PATCH, POST, PUT` for the JSON API. So, I believe that what you are experiencing with the `OPTIONS` method should be expected behavior.